# Where can I get a copy of the Quran using arabic font for an e-reader

Tags: quran

I've recently purchased a Kindle Paperwhite 7th Generation.

I'd like to download a PDF (or any format that works on e-book readers, in general) of the Quran but I'd like for it to use an arabic font instead of images to render the arabic because then I can highlight ayahs and add my notes while I'm studying it.

There are a few online but apparently some of them have errors in them.
Can someone point me to a credible source where I can download/purchase a copy of the Quran in arabic font?

Comment: Is [this](http://tauheed-sunnat.com/bk/quran/Quran-e-Karim/Quran-e-Karim%20-%20Arabic%20with%20English%20Translation.pdf) alright?

Comment: Hi @azam, I was hoping for a PDF with arabic only.

Comment: This sort of "book recommendation" question doesn't work well under the Stack Exchange model and are considered non-constructive here (see http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/261/22). You and others are more than free to discuss this in [chat].

Comment: You can see this video and download the kuran large text with black or white background: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1bXjCjcp5OA

Comment: I created a copy with a support for text resizing and the complete tashkel for free: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B089KN9KB2

Answer (score 1):

I also use kindle.

In kindle, you can go to the `Apps` tab and search the word `Quran`. There you would get some apps for Quran. I found two useful and using one named`iQuran Lite`.

You can also order it by visiting [this link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005H2I0AS) from your account.

Jajakallah. Don't forget me in your Dua.

Comment: I'm using the Kindle Paperwhite 7th Generation. Doesn't seem to be supported, thanks for suggesting though.